# Shadow in Highcharts bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I want to give 5 px shadow in right side of the bar. Is it possible?

[image: I want to give 5 px shadow in right side o]

Comment: check the docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.shadow

Comment: That is a box shadow, but i need inner shadow in the bars as you can see in the image.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the Renderer which allows to add custom paths in chart. Knowing that, catch the load event and iterate on each series point, adding line in right side.

```
chart: {
  type: 'column',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var chart = this,
        series = chart.series,
        each = Highcharts.each,
        r = chart.renderer,
        borderWidth  = 2,
        x,y;

      each(series, function(s, i) {
        each(s.data, function(p, j) {
                        x = p.plotX + chart.plotLeft + (p.pointWidth / 2);
                        y = p.plotY + chart.plotTop + borderWidth;

          r.path(['M', x, y, 'L', x, y + p.shapeArgs.height])
          .attr({
            zIndex: 10,
            'stroke-width': borderWidth,
            'stroke': 'gray'
          })
          .add()
        });
      });
    }
  }
},
```

Example:
- http://jsfiddle.net/2reombm7/

Comment: Awesome one. Thank you so much. Can you please mark this question up as a useful, someone marked it down :(